# Javascript onfocusout event does not work

Tags: javascript, html, validation, dom-events

I've been working on a notebook webapp, I want to make form validation, if the user leave the (noteTitle) or (note) empty, a message will show an error for him, I'm using onfocusout event to make the message appear when ever the user had gone from the input field leaving it empty, but the event won't work for me.

Here is my code:

```js
const main = document.getElementById("main");
const add = document.getElementById("add"); //new note
const submit = document.getElementById("submit"); //submit the new note
const cancel = document.getElementById("cancel");
const screen = document.getElementById("screen");
const ul = document.getElementById("list");
const del = document.getElementById("delete"); 
const note = document.getElementById("note");
const back = document.getElementById("back");
const noteTitle = document.getElementById("note-title");
const inputTitle = document.getElementById("input-title");
const err1 = document.getElementById("err1");
const err2 = document.getElementById("err2");
const err3 = document.getElementById("err3");
const text = document.getElementById("text");

let flag1 = false;
let flag2 = false;
let flag3 = false;

let mynotes = {};
let i = 1;

add.addEventListener('click', function(){
    main.style.display = "block";
    submit.style.display = "inline";
    cancel.style.display = "inline";
    add.style.display = "none";
    screen.style.display = "none";
    del.style.display = "none";
    back.style.display = "none";
    inputTitle.style.display = "block"
});

noteTitle.addEventListener('onfocusout', function(){
    title = noteTitle.value;
    if (title.length < 3){
        err1.style.display = "block";
        flag1 = true;
        console.log(flag1);
    }else {
        err1.style.display = "none";
        flag1 = false;
    }

    if (mynotes.hasOwnProperty(title)){
        err3.style.display = "block";
        flag3 = true;
    } else{
        err3.style.display = "none";
        flag3 = false;
    }
});

note.addEventListener('onfocusout', function(){
    newNote= note.value;
    if (newNote === ""){
        err2.style.display = "block";
        flag2 = true;
    } else {
        err2.style.display = "none";
        flag2 = false;
    }
});

submit.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if (!flag1 && !flag2 && !flag3) {
        newNote = newNote.replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
        mynotes[title] = newNote;

        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.setAttribute('class','item');
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(title));
        ul.appendChild(li);
        main.style.display = "none";
        screen.style.display = "block";
        submit.style.display = "none";
        cancel.style.display = "none";
        add.style.display = "inline";
        del.style.display = "none";
        back.style.display = "none";
        inputTitle.style.display = "none";
        note.value = "";
        noteTitle.value = "";
    } 
});



ul.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    node = event.target;
    item = event.target.textContent;
    text.innerHTML = mynotes[item];
    fullnote.style.display = "block";
    main.style.display = "none";
    submit.style.display = "none";
    add.style.display = "none";
    screen.style.display = "none";
    cancel.style.display = "none";
    del.style.display = "inline";
    back.style.display = "inline";
    inputTitle.style.display = "none";
});

del.addEventListener('click', function(){
    ul.removeChild(node);
    delete mynotes[item];
    main.style.display = "none";
    screen.style.display = "block";
    submit.style.display = "none";
    add.style.display = "inline";
    fullnote.style.display = "none";
    back.style.display = "none";
    del.style.display = "none";
    inputTitle.style.display = "none";
});

cancel.addEventListener('click', function(){
    note.value = "";
    main.style.display = "none";
    screen.style.display = "block";
    submit.style.display = "none";
    add.style.display = "inline";
    fullnote.style.display = "none";
    del.style.display = "none";
    back.style.display = "none";
    cancel.style.display = "none";
    inputTitle.style.display = "none";
});

back.addEventListener('click', function(){
    main.style.display = "none";
    screen.style.display = "block";
    submit.style.display = "none";
    add.style.display = "inline";
    fullnote.style.display = "none";
    back.style.display = "none";
    del.style.display = "none";
    inputTitle.style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
#container {
    background-color: rgb(253, 248, 177);
}

#header, #footer {
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}

#footer {
  bottom: 0;
}

#screen, #input-title {
  margin-top: 2em;
} 

#title {
    color: white;
    padding-top: 7px; 
}

#cancel, #submit, #back {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#add {
    font-size: 20px; 
}

#delete, #cancel, #submit {
    display: none;
}

#input-title {
    display: none;
}

#main {
    display: none;
}


#note {
    resize: none;
}


#fullnote {
    display: none;
}

#back {
    display: none;
}

#err1 {
    color: red;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: none;
}

#err2 {
    color: red;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: none;
}

#err3 {
    color: red;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- link to css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <title>Notebook</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    
    <div class="container-fluid min-vh-100 d-flex flex-column" id="container">

      <!-- header -->
      <div class="row align-items-start bg-info container-fluid" id="header">
        <div class="col text-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn" id="cancel">&#10007;</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn" id="back">&#8617;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">
          <h4 id="title">Notebook</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn" id="submit">&#10004;</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <br />

      <!-- Screen list show -->
        <div class="row" id="screen">
            <div class="col-12">
                <ul id="list">
                  
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Note show -->
      <div class="row" id="fullnote">
            <div class="col-12">
            <br><br>
              <p id="text"> 
              </p>
            </div>
        </div>

      <!-- input for note title -->
      <div class="row" id="input-title">
        <div class="col">
            <input type="text" maxlength="20" class="form-control" placeholder="Note title" value="" id="note-title">
            <p id="err1">&emsp;Title must be at least 3 characters</p>
            <p id="err3">&emsp;There is a note with this title</p>
          </div>
      </div>
      <br />
      <!-- textarea for writing note -->
      <div class="row flex-grow-1">
        <div class="col" id="main">
            <textarea class="form-control textarea h-100" value="" placeholder="write note" id="note"></textarea>
            <p id="err2">&emsp;Note can not be empty</p>
          </div>
      </div>

      <br />

      
      <!-- footer -->
      <div class="row align-items-end container-fluid" id="footer">
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-start" style="padding: 10px; padding-left: 25px;">
          <button id="add" class="btn btn-info rounded-circle"><h4 style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">&#x2b;</h4></button>
          <button id="delete" class="btn btn-info rounded-circle">&#128465;</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    
    </div>

    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Your question is valid, but you should try to make your examples codes minimal, and leave only what is needed to demonstrate your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onfocusout` is not the event. The event is `focusout`
`onfocusout` is used like this

```
<input type="text" onfocusout='myfunc()'>
```

```js
const main = document.getElementById("main");
const add = document.getElementById("add"); //new note
const submit = document.getElementById("submit"); //submit the new note
const cancel = document.getElementById("cancel");
const screen = document.getElementById("screen");
const ul = document.getElementById("list");
const del = document.getElementById("delete"); 
const note = document.getElementById("note");
const back = document.getElementById("back");
const noteTitle = document.getElementById("note-title");
const inputTitle = document.getElementById("input-title");
const err1 = document.getElementById("err1");
const err2 = document.getElementById("err2");
const err3 = document.getElementById("err3");
const text = document.getElementById("text");

let flag1 = false;
let flag2 = false;
let flag3 = false;

let mynotes = {};
let i = 1;

add.addEventListener('click', function(){
    main.style.display = "block";
    submit.style.display = "inline";
    cancel.style.display = "inline";
    add.style.display = "none";
    screen.style.display = "none";
    del.style.display = "none";
    back.style.display = "none";
    inputTitle.style.display = "block"
});

noteTitle.addEventListener('focusout', function(){
    title = noteTitle.value;
    if (title.length < 3){
        err1.style.display = "block";
        flag1 = true;
        console.log(flag1);
    }else {
        err1.style.display = "none";
        flag1 = false;
    }

    if (mynotes.hasOwnProperty(title)){
        err3.style.display = "block";
        flag3 = true;
    } else{
        err3.style.display = "none";
        flag3 = false;
    }
});

note.addEventListener('onfocusout', function(){
    newNote= note.value;
    if (newNote === ""){
        err2.style.display = "block";
        flag2 = true;
    } else {
        err2.style.display = "none";
        flag2 = false;
    }
});

submit.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if (!flag1 && !flag2 && !flag3) {
        newNote = newNote.replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
        mynotes[title] = newNote;

        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.setAttribute('class','item');
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(title));
        ul.appendChild(li);
        main.style.display = "none";
        screen.style.display = "block";
        submit.style.display = "none";
        cancel.style.display = "none";
        add.style.display = "inline";
        del.style.display = "none";
        back.style.display = "none";
        inputTitle.style.display = "none";
        note.value = "";
        noteTitle.value = "";
    } 
});



ul.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    node = event.target;
    item = event.target.textContent;
    text.innerHTML = mynotes[item];
    fullnote.style.display = "block";
    main.style.display = "none";
    submit.style.display = "none";
    add.style.display = "none";
    screen.style.display = "none";
    cancel.style.display = "none";
    del.style.display = "inline";
    back.style.display = "inline";
    inputTitle.style.display = "none";
});

del.addEventListener('click', function(){
    ul.removeChild(node);
    delete mynotes[item];
    main.style.display = "none";
    screen.style.display = "block";
    submit.style.display = "none";
    add.style.display = "inline";
    fullnote.style.display = "none";
    back.style.display = "none";
    del.style.display = "none";
    inputTitle.style.display = "none";
});

cancel.addEventListener('click', function(){
    note.value = "";
    main.style.display = "none";
    screen.style.display = "block";
    submit.style.display = "none";
    add.style.display = "inline";
    fullnote.style.display = "none";
    del.style.display = "none";
    back.style.display = "none";
    cancel.style.display = "none";
    inputTitle.style.display = "none";
});

back.addEventListener('click', function(){
    main.style.display = "none";
    screen.style.display = "block";
    submit.style.display = "none";
    add.style.display = "inline";
    fullnote.style.display = "none";
    back.style.display = "none";
    del.style.display = "none";
    inputTitle.style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
#container {
    background-color: rgb(253, 248, 177);
}

#header, #footer {
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}

#footer {
  bottom: 0;
}

#screen, #input-title {
  margin-top: 2em;
} 

#title {
    color: white;
    padding-top: 7px; 
}

#cancel, #submit, #back {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#add {
    font-size: 20px; 
}

#delete, #cancel, #submit {
    display: none;
}

#input-title {
    display: none;
}

#main {
    display: none;
}


#note {
    resize: none;
}


#fullnote {
    display: none;
}

#back {
    display: none;
}

#err1 {
    color: red;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: none;
}

#err2 {
    color: red;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: none;
}

#err3 {
    color: red;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- link to css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <title>Notebook</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    
    <div class="container-fluid min-vh-100 d-flex flex-column" id="container">

      <!-- header -->
      <div class="row align-items-start bg-info container-fluid" id="header">
        <div class="col text-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn" id="cancel">&#10007;</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn" id="back">&#8617;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">
          <h4 id="title">Notebook</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn" id="submit">&#10004;</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <br />

      <!-- Screen list show -->
        <div class="row" id="screen">
            <div class="col-12">
                <ul id="list">
                  
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Note show -->
      <div class="row" id="fullnote">
            <div class="col-12">
            <br><br>
              <p id="text"> 
              </p>
            </div>
        </div>

      <!-- input for note title -->
      <div class="row" id="input-title">
        <div class="col">
            <input type="text" maxlength="20" class="form-control" placeholder="Note title" value="" id="note-title">
            <p id="err1">&emsp;Title must be at least 3 characters</p>
            <p id="err3">&emsp;There is a note with this title</p>
          </div>
      </div>
      <br />
      <!-- textarea for writing note -->
      <div class="row flex-grow-1">
        <div class="col" id="main">
            <textarea class="form-control textarea h-100" value="" placeholder="write note" id="note"></textarea>
            <p id="err2">&emsp;Note can not be empty</p>
          </div>
      </div>

      <br />

      
      <!-- footer -->
      <div class="row align-items-end container-fluid" id="footer">
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-start" style="padding: 10px; padding-left: 25px;">
          <button id="add" class="btn btn-info rounded-circle"><h4 style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">&#x2b;</h4></button>
          <button id="delete" class="btn btn-info rounded-circle">&#128465;</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    
    </div>

    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes it does, it's on the input element inside of `#input-title`, I thought the same thing.

Comment: [More here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focusout) on `focusout` in modern browsers. `onFocusOut` only worked in IE when originally included in the spec.